# Swift - trying to loop through stringValue from text field

Tags: loops, swift

I'm trying to iterate over every character from a text field,

here's how I did it:

```
@IBOutlet var needTranslate : NSTextField
for i in needTranslate.stringValue{
```

then I get an error: SourceKitService terminated

and it happens only when I try to loop through this string value. I understand that's a bug but am I doing something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a compiler bug to me.

- Your code causes a runtime exception
  of the swift compiler itself. This should not happen even for completely wrong source code.
- Your code looks in fact correct (to me) because the return value of `stringValue`
  is an *implicitly unwrapped* optional string.

The problem can be reproduced with

```
var s : String! = "foo"
for i in s {
    println(i)
}
```

I cannot see from the documentation why a `for ... in ...` loop should not work with
an implicitly unwrapped string, so I would recommend to file a bug report at Apple.

As a workaround, you can treat the return value of `stringValue` like a "normal"
optional and unwrap it explicitly with an optional binding:

```
if let str = needTranslate.stringValue {
    for i in str {
         println(i)  
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that trying to loop over an implicitly unwrapped string in the playground crashes the compiler (and Xcode itself, on my machine). It's definitely a bug.

Comment: Also it works as expected for other implicitly unwrapped types, such as an `Array<String>`